# Hacer INSERT en una tabla en dos servidores distintos

Tags: php, mysql

mi pregunta es si es posible realizar un insert en 2 servidores distintos creando dos funciones de conexion y que cada una apunte al servidor deseado.

Lo que he intentado es lo siquiente:

```
$class->link1()->query("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES('holaaa')");
$class->link1()->close();
$class->link2()->query("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES('holaaa')");
$class->link2()->close();
```

Pero lo que hace es que inserta dos veces el registro en el servidor 1 pero no ingresa nada en el servidor 2. Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Es totalmente posible, si desde el lugar en que lo intentas tienes permiso para conectarte a dichos servidores. ¿Estás seguro de que `link2()` apunta realmente al servidor 2?

Comment: pon el codigo de link1 y link2